# Вычисление input co значением

Tags: javascript, html5

```
function scorerap() 
{
    document.getElementById('kolrap').value = document.getElementById('tiraj').value /
            document.getElementById('kolnarap').value; 
}
document.getElementById('tiraj').addEventListener('input', scorerap);
document.getElementById('kolnarap').addEventListener('input', scorerap);
```

Значение ('kolrap') уже посчитано и находится в инпуте1.
Но чтобы формула работала, нужно нажать хотя бы 1 клавишу в этом инпуте1.
Как сделать так, чтобы оно сразу хватало значение?

Comment: А каким образом в инпуте должно появится новое значение, если не путём ввода с клавиатуры?

Comment: Что за `инпут1`? В коде его нет. Какое значение вы хотите "хватать"? Почему значение для `kolrap` лежит в другом `input`-е, а не в нём самом? Если нужно скопировать значение из одного `input`-a в другой, то при чём здесь формула?

Comment: а что из этого является input1? не могли бы вы дополнить ваш вопрос разметкой

Comment: Скопировала функцию себе и добавила три инпута, частное автоматически пересчитывается и без проблем отображается в инпуте kolrap. Не могли бы Вы предоставить полный код? Не совсем понятно, чего Вы хотите добиться.